# Why does this line of python break emacs python-mode indentation?

Tags: python, emacs

For some reason, in the below code:

```
for statement in statements:
    speakerAndSpeech = findSpeaker(statement)
    speaker = speakerAndSpeech[0]
    speech = speakerAndSepech[1]
    ## Everything above the below line indents correctly, like this
    self.statements.append(createStatement(statements.index(statement), speech, speaker, self.meeting["id"])
    ## Everything below the above line indents out here

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I'm using `python-mode.el`

Comment: Check your parentheses in the "breaking" line.

Comment: You are missing a paren on that line. Did you try @JonathanJin's suggestion? Did it work? if so, let us know so we can post an answer or perhaps close as a minor syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented: caused by a missing parenthesis at last code-line in block:

```
...self.meeting["id"])
```

Maybe you want:

```
   ...self.meeting["id"]))
```